# How to get values from input time

Tags: javascript

```
function update() {
  var object_one = $('#start_time');
  var object_two = $('#total');
  var object_three = $('#end-time');
  var my_input = object_one.val();
  var my_put = object_three.val();
  var my_output = my_put - my_input;
  object_two.val(my_output);
}


<th colspan="2"> Monday</th>
   <td> <input id="start_time" type="time"></td>
   <td> <input id= "end-time" type= "time"></td>
   <td> <input id="start_time" type="time"></td>
   <td> <input id= "end-time" type= "time"></td>
   <td> in</td>
   <td>out </td>
   <td> in</td>
   <td>out </td>
```

I've already defined the values of start and end time... i just don't how to subtract the times to get my output. I don't know if I'm setting the values correctly and that's why I get NaN as my output. It's a TIMESHEET assignment, so we have to add the time's in each row etc. I'm really new to this, help.

Comment: Where is the HTML? Are *start_time* and *end-time* date or time inputs?

Comment: @jack please add your HTML code

Comment: sure thing^ they are time inputs @RobG

Comment: You should "parse" your input value and convert to a proper type. In your case, you have to convert your strings to Date objects and then you can subtract and get the timestamp interval.

Comment: Multiple elements having the same value for `id` attribute is not advised

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at the value of your time inputs, they are strings. You can learn more about this [type of time input here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/time). The thing to note is that the value will always be a string in the format HH:MM (24 hour clock). This means it's easy to parse into hours/minutes.

I've made a function for you to do exactly this. You can find it here.

```
function ParseTime(timeString) {
  var timeMatcher = /(\d\d):(\d\d)/;
  var result  = timeMatcher.exec(timeString);

  // The first result (result 0) is the full string,
  // the second is the number of hours, the third is the number of minutes.
  var hours = Number(result[1]);
  var minutes = Number(result[2]);

  // returns the time in number of minutes.
  return (hours * 60) + minutes;
}
```